# Scala Play evolutions applied before starting server in PROD

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-evolutions

In the Play 2.4 documentation, it says

> to enable autoApply for all evolutions, you might set play.evolutions.autoApply=true in application.conf or in a system property.

But in PROD mode, I want to apply the evolution (do a DB migration) before I start the server.

My question is besides, set it in `application.conf` and `-Dplay.evolutions.autoApply=true` Are there any other ways I can manual trigger the play evolutions?

Comment: As far as I know, that's the only way. I don't understand what you need. The evolution is applied and then the application is abailable to access. Why that isn't enough for you?

Comment: @David I want to apply evolution db migration script before I run activator run